# FirebaseDynamicLinks why doesnt work in app background?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using firebase_dynamic_links in my Flutter App. I did step by step from the document.

```
  void fetchLinkData(BuildContext context) async {
    PendingDynamicLinkData link =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    handleLinkData(context, link);
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
      onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
        handleLinkData(context, dynamicLink);
      },
    );
  }

  void handleLinkData(BuildContext context, PendingDynamicLinkData data) {
    final Uri uri = data?.link;
    if (uri != null) {
      final queryParams = uri.queryParameters;
      if (queryParams.length > 0) {
        String prodId = queryParams["shared"];
        if (prodId != null) {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ProductDetails(),
              ));
          context.read<SupplierRepo>().getProductDetails(prodId);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When I click the link while the application is closed, it does the process correctly, but when I click the link while the application is open in the background, I get this output:

```
E / FA (26205): Name is reserved. Type, name: event, dynamic_link_app_open
E / FA (26205): Invalid event name. Event will not be logged (FE): dynamic_link_app_open
```

EDIT [20.01.2021]: I texted firebase support yesterday and they replied to me. The reply is:

"I've tried replicating the issue on my end, and I was also able to reproduce the same error. This looks to be a bug on our end, and I've escalated this to our engineers for deeper investigation. However, I can't share any timelines yet on when the fix will be available. We'll be sure to address things though once we've identified the root cause of the issue. For further updates, please keep an eye out on our release notes, or check the Analytics reports from time to time.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention, and apologies for the inconvenience this may have caused you."